# What is the format for javascript datetime that Google Requires for charts?

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-visualization

I'm working with the google chart and I've tried so many date formats and nothing is working. I'm ready to just use moments format feature, however I need the google date format for datetime.

Thanks!

Comment: google docs are messy, why I'm asking for a solution after a week of searching.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with node.js or momentjs. Just because you happen to use them, does not make them relevant for your question.

Comment: It does, because I'll be using moment.js on node to send my json over to the frontend. Plus Patsy Issa sent Java code and not Javascript. That helps none -__-

Comment: @JemiloII where do you see java? Really learn to read docs before coming in here with questions that can be solved by Googling!

Comment: **google.visualization.DateFormat

Formats a JavaScript Date value in a variety of ways, including "January 1, 2009," "1/1/09" and "Jan 1, 2009.** Read before trying to be a smartass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of chart are you trying to use from Google?
Check this out it has some example code, you can also play around in the "Visualization Playground"

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotatedtimeline
https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#annotated_time_line

In that example they are using Javascript Date objects.
There's also a section on the Date Format (date or datetime):
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotatedtimeline#Data_Format

Answer (score 2):

The "datetime" data type requires a javascript [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), eg:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('datetime', 'Date and time');
data.addRow([new Date(2014, 5, 24, 11, 35, 24)]); // June 24 2014 11:35:24
```

If you are looking for the specs of the DateFormat patterns, they use a subset of the [ICU Date Format pattern set](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classSimpleDateFormat.html#_details).